# Django use oneToManyField or ForeignKey, which one should i use?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

Let's say i have two models (Patient, Doctor)
A doctor may have many patient but a patient must have one doctor. I want to link patient with doctor. I want to show list of patient a doctor have on doctor's page and name of doctor in patient page. On both model should i use ForeignKey or ManyToManyField? Which one should i use & why?

Comment: You said it: a patient must have one doctor. If you mean "exactly or at most one" doctor, then use a FK on the Patient model to Doctor. That way, many patients can be linked to the same doctor, but none of them can have more than one doctor.

Comment: If i use fk, can i show list of patients that doctor have?

Comment: Sure, `doc.patient_set.all()` will give you the pateints of `doc`, given the default naming.